# ionic error [An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.]

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I get an error when building with ionic

```
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
Error: xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Users/kuniatsu/src/ionic/app_name/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1026:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/xcodebuild-failed-exit-code-65/4424
I read to this url page.
This page was written as [***You need to login to that developer account in xcode.***].
I setting developer account to xcode .

Do you know a solution?

```
kuniatsu$ ionic --version
6.5.0
```

Comment: Try to run build command with --verbose and add the result in the question.

Comment: sorry,  Restarting mac was successful.